# Enumeration of a certain sequence III

Tags: programming, combinatorics, sets

Let’s call a collection $\mathcal{F} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$ satisfying:

- $\emptyset, X \in \mathcal{F}$
- For all $U, V \in \mathcal{F}$ it holds that $U \cap V \in \mathcal{F}$.

**special**.

We can evaluate the number of special collections on a finite labeled set of *n* elements via the following code:

```
    Table[Length[
  Select[Subsets[Subsets[Range[n]]], 
   And[MemberQ[#, {}], MemberQ[#, Range[n]], 
     SubsetQ[#, Intersection @@@ Tuples[#, 2]]] &]], {n, 0, 4}]
```

Let us introduce the following three conditions that special collection may satisfy:

($\mathrm S_2$) For all $x,y \in X, \ x\neq y$ there exists $H \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $X \setminus H \in \mathcal{F}$ and $x \in H$ and $y \in X \setminus H $.

($\mathrm S_3$) For all $x \in X$ and $U \in \mathcal{F}, x \notin U$ there exists $H \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $X \setminus H \in \mathcal{F}$ and $x \in H$ and $U \subseteq X \setminus H $.

Let us thus by $a_2(n)$, $a_3(n)$, respectively, denote the denote the number of $\mathrm S_2$, that is, $\mathrm S_3$ special collections on a finite labeled set of *n* elements.

However, I am not sure how to alter the code such that the condition $\mathrm S_2$, that is, $\mathrm S_3$ is satisfied as well

**Can someone help me to write a code to enumerate the sequences $a_2(n)$, $a_3(n)$?**

I would like to offer my sincere graditude in advance!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140314/discussion-on-question-by-user227351-enumeration-of-a-certain-sequence-iii).

Comment: Been a while but… condition S_2 makes it a Haussdorf topology?

Comment: Not quite. But I get the association you are having. These families are not topologies, but the statement of the axiom is similar to the Hausdorff ($T_2$) axiom.

Comment: This is a matroid, correct? It might be speedier to just compute the set of bases, and verify the basis exchange axiom on those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution for $S_2$.**

Here is a partial answer (for $S_2$ only), to give you some inspiration.

First, we'll define a function `special[n]` that generates all special collections (and $a(n)$, of course, is just the length of `special[n]`):

```
special[n_] :=
  Select[
   Subsets[Subsets[Range[n]]],
   And[
     MemberQ[#, {}],
     MemberQ[#, Range[n]],
     SubsetQ[#, Intersection @@@ Tuples[#, 2]]] &
   ];
a[n_] := Length@special[n];

Table[a[n], {n, 4}] (* {1, 4, 45, 2271} *)
```

Let's write your $S_2$ condition on $x$, $y$, and $F$:

```
s2[x_, y_, F_, n_] :=
 MemberQ[F,
  _?(H |-> With[{H1 = Complement[Range[n], H]},
      MemberQ[F, H1] && MemberQ[H, x] && MemberQ[H1, y]])]
```

Some comments on what's going on:

1. `MemberQ[list, _?f]` returns true if at least one member of `list` satisfies the predicate `f` - similar to `Length@Select[list, f]>0` but faster since it doesn't need to calculate `f` on every element of list.
2. We use a handy `|->` shortcut to define a function with a named argument $H$. `With` defines a shortcut for the complement of $H$, and the rest is a straightforward translation of your condition.
3. Note that we need $n$ as an explicit argument to $s_2$ in order to calculate the complement.

We can check how $s_2$ works with specific arguments $x=1$ and $y=2$ in `special[2]`:

```
Column@special[2]
(*
{{{}, {1, 2}}},
{{{}, {1}, {1, 2}}},
{{{}, {2}, {1, 2}}},
{{{}, {1}, {2}, {1, 2}}}
 *)

Select[special[2], s2[1, 2, #, 2] &] (* {{{}, {1}, {2}, {1, 2}}} *)
```

Indeed, it's easy to see that only one family - all subsets of $\{1,2\}$ - satisfies $s_2$.

Now, for a given family $F$, we'll check whether it satisfies $s_2$ for all possible pairs $x, y$ (we only need to check for the subsets of length 2 given that the condition is symmetrical on $x, y$). Note that we can re-use the symbol $s_2$ as the function below has arity of 2 and the one defined before has arity of 4:

```
s2[F_, n_] := AllTrue[
  Subsets[Range[n], {2}],
  s2[#[[1]], #[[2]], F, n] &]
```

Finally,

```
a2[n_] := Length@Select[special[n], s2[#, n] &]
```

Here is a table for the values of $a_2(n)$ for $n=1\dots4$:

```
Table[a2[n], {n, 4}] (* {1, 1, 4, 167} *)
```

**Answer for $S_3$.**

I also wrote the code for $a_3(n)$, and the answer is $1,2,8,121$ for $n=1,\dots,4$.

It was pretty straightforward to do. But in general, I'm not a big fan of answering questions of the type "please write some code for me" :). You would get much bigger mileage from learning some programming basics and showing the places where you got stuck, as opposed to just asking strangers to solve a problem for you.

**(Update) Solution for $S_3$.**

After some consideration, I decided that's it would be too cruel to not share the solution. So here it is.

The $S_3$ condition is very similar to $S_2$:

```
s3[x_, U_, F_, n_] :=
 MemberQ[F,
  _?(H |-> With[{H1 = Complement[Range[n], H]},
      MemberQ[F, H1] && MemberQ[H, x] && SubsetQ[H1, U]])]
```

The somewhat tricky part is to generate all pairs $(x,U)$ for a given $F$. I suggest you to meditate on the following piece of code - most of the ingredients are as described above, `FreeQ` is the opposite of `MemberQ`, and `Flatten[_, 1`] can be looked up in the documentation.

```
allPairs[F_, n_] := 
 Flatten[(x |-> ({x, #} & /@ Select[F, FreeQ[#, x] &])) /@ Range[n], 
  1]
```

After this, the `s3[F,n]` definition is very similar to $s_2$:

```
s3[F_, n_] := AllTrue[
  allPairs[F, n],
  s3[#[[1]], #[[2]], F, n] &
  ]
```

And we are ready to calculate $a_3(n)$:

```
a3[n_] := Length@Select[special[n], s3[#, n] &]
Table[a3[n], {n, 4}] (* {1, 2, 8, 121} *)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I completely understand how such straightforward answers deprive individuals of programming skills. However, I truly needed some values of those sequences for my ongoing research, and I don’t have time to invest in programming.

Comment: Would you mind providing the solution for $\mathrm I$ also since it is an unrelated condition?

Comment: You are welcome! To set your expectation, I’m unlikely to work on the last part - it’s slightly more involved and technical, and I have already satisfied my curiosity by working on the first two parts.

Comment: Re: “I don’t have time to invest in programming” - my friendly advice would be to find some time to invest, esp. given that with WL is extremely useful tool for a mathematician. “An Elementary Introduction” by S. Wolfram is a good start: https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/

Comment: Im not interested in bounties - I have enough karma already ;)

Comment: When I look at the solution families for $a_2(3)$, I get {{}, {1}, {2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}} as a solution. However, {2} and {3} cannot be separated by the rules of $\mathrm S_2$. Where did the code go wrong?

Comment: Perhaps then $\mathrm S_3$ needs to be altered also?

Comment: You are write - there was a bug in the code for `s2[x_,y_,F_,n_]`: `Range[2]` should have been `Range[n]`. I fixed it above. `s3` doesn't seem to have this bug.

Comment: You can look at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/275380/revisions to see the exact place that was changed.

Comment: Well then, I think this concludes it and that your answer deserves the bounty (@thorimur) :) !

Comment: “Right”, not “write”, of course!