# Enumeration of a sequence involving closure operators

Tags: programming, combinatorics, sets

Let us call a collection $\mathcal{F} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$ *special* if it satisfies the following two conditions:

1. $\emptyset, X \in \mathcal{F}$
2. For all $U, V \in \mathcal{F}$, it holds that $U \cap V \in \mathcal{F}$.

We can list and evaluate the number of special collections on a finite labeled set of $n$ elements with the following code:

```
Table[Length[
  Select[Subsets[Subsets[Range[n]]], 
   And[MemberQ[#, {}], MemberQ[#, Range[n]], 
     SubsetQ[#, Intersection @@@ Tuples[#, 2]]] &]], {n, 0, 4}]
```

Let us introduce another condition that special collections may satisfy:

3. For all $S \subseteq X$, the statement $ \forall x,y \in S : \mathrm{cl}(\left \{ x,y \right \})\subseteq S$ implies $S \in \mathcal{F}$,

where the closure $\mathrm{cl}(A)$ is defined as $$\mathrm{cl}(A)=\bigcap \left \{ U : U\supseteq A \wedge U  \in \mathcal{F} \right \}$$ for all $A \subseteq X$. In the condition 3, it may also be that $x=y$.

Let $a(n)$ denote the number of special collections on a finite labeled set of $n$ elements that also satisfy condition 3.

**How can I write a code to list all such collections and calculate $a(n)$ for $n \leq 4$?**

For example, $a(2)=4$ since all of the collections;

{{}, {1,2}}

{{}, {1}, {1,2}}

{{}, {2}, {1,2}}

{{}, {1}, {2}, {1,2}}

satisfy conditions 1, 2 and 3.

I have posted a similar question: [Enumeration of a certain sequence III](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/274881/enumeration-of-a-certain-sequence-iii) which may help.

Comment: Thank you. Did it.

Comment: I missed this in your definition: it could be $\forall_S\forall_{\{x,y\}}(\text{abc}\implies\text{xyz})$ or $\forall_S(\forall_{\{x,y\}}\text{abc})\implies\text{xyz}$.  The latter is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Condition 3 is equivalent to $\forall_{S\not\in\mathcal F}\neg\forall_{\{x,y\}\subseteq S}\mathrm{cl}(\{x,y\})\subseteq S$.  This can be seen by expanding the logical operators.

This code is a straightforward implementation.  It isn't fast, I'm curious if a solution involving `ForAll` and `Exists` is faster.

```
Remove[singletonsAndPairs, n, P, closure, condition1Q, condition2Q, condition3Q, P123]
singletonsAndPairs[A_List] := Subsets[A, {1, 2}]
n = 4;
P = Subsets@Range@n;
closure[_, A_] := Intersection @@ Select[, SubsetQ[#, A] &](*\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Intersection]\), \(A \[SubsetEqual] # \[SubsetEqual] \)]#\)*)
condition1Q[_] := SubsetQ[, {{}, Range@n}]
condition2Q[_] := SubsetQ[, Intersection @@@ singletonsAndPairs@](*{U\[Intersection]V:U,V\[Element]}\[SubsetEqual]*)
condition3Q[_] := AllTrue[Complement[P, ], S \[Function] \[Not] AllTrue[singletonsAndPairs@S, SubsetQ[S, closure[, #]] &]]
P123 = Select[Subsets@P, condition1Q@# \[And] condition2Q@# \[And] condition3Q@# &];
Length@P123
```

We get $a(1)=1$, $a(2)=4$, $a(3)=45$ and $a(4)=2062$.

A smarter method is needed for $a(5)$; my notebook runs out of memory.

Comment: Replace `//Length` with `//Column[#,Frame->All]&`, or delete the `//...` entirely (the result is a List, and you can find its length, or frame it in a column, or anything else).

Comment: This sequence appears to be https://oeis.org/A334255 which seems to count different closure operators.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146873/discussion-between-adam-and-user227351).

Comment: Thank you very much! What if we replaced condition 3 with: For all $S \subseteq X$, the statement $ \forall x_1, x_2, ..., x_k \in S : \mathrm{cl}(\left \{ x_1, x_2, ..., x_k \right \})\subseteq S$ implies $S \in \mathcal{F}$ for arbitrary $k$?

Comment: Is it straightforward to alter the code?

Comment: The code could be made more explicit; I'll remove the `With`s to make the variables a bit easier to read.